# Kubernetes TPS drops to O when Pods comes from state 0/1 to 1/1 in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

When 1 new POD is created by Autoscaling or Pod deletion or auto POD restart traffic on remaining 49 pods stops taking request and I see 0 TPS for 5 to 10 sec
Please suggest the reasons as I did all the changes at deployment level

Comment: do you have `readiness` or any other probe implemented ?

Comment: Hi @dhananjay, welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide more details: How did you setup your cluster? Is it bare-metal or did you use some cloud providor? Did you use [rediness / liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)? You said, that you did all the changes. What did you exactly do? Could you paste your yaml files? You can also check pod's logs.